# How to bind one model for creating dropdownlist and second model for textboxes using strongly typed view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

1st model:

```
public class VehicleMake
{
    [Key]
    public int MakeId { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

2nd Model:

```
public class VehicleModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public DateTime Year { get; set; }
    public int MakeId { get; set; }
    public VehicleMake VehcileMake { get; set; }
}
```

How to pass two models as strongly typed view.

my view  has 1) one dropdownlist which bind make and makeid from VehicleMake class
2) one textbox as Model which binds from vehicleModle class

Please suggest how to create a view using multiple models?

```
@model MvcApplication1.Data.ViewVMModel
....
<h2>CreateModel</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Select Make")</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.VehicleMake,new SelectList(Model. "MakeId","Make")))</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enter Model </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.VehcileModel)</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `VehcileModel` is a complex object and you cannot bind a textbox to a complex object. Are you wanting to display a dropdownlist to select a `Make` and then have textboxes to enter data for `Model` and `Year`? (and tables are for tabular data - do not use them for layout)

Comment: Yes, Save the data by selecting Vehicle Make in dorpdownlist and enter Model name (eg: camry) and year in a textbox

Comment: how are you populating the list of VehicleMake in dropdown? by model or by viewbag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're editing data so first step is to create a view model (add other validation attributes as required).

```
public class VehicleVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
    public DateTime? Year { get; set; } // make nullable to protect against under-posting attacks
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
    [Display(Name = "Make")]
    public int? SelectedMake { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem? MakesList { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method, initialize an instance of your view model, populate it and pass it to the view

```
var makes = db.VehicleMakes; // get the Makes from the database
VehicleVM vehicle = new VehicleVM()
{
    MakesList = new SelectList(makes, "MakeId", "Make")
};
return View(vehicle);
```

and in the view

```
@model VehicleVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedMake)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMake, Model.MakesList)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedMake)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Model)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Model)

    ....
```

Which will post back to

```
public ActionResult Create(VehicleVM vehicle)
```

Answer (score 0):

your Viewmodel should be something like this

```
public VehicleModel VehicleModel { get; set; }
public List<VehicleMake> VehcileMakeList { get; set; }
```

and in your view

```
@model MvcApplication1.Data.ViewVMModel
....
<h2>CreateModel</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.Label("Select Make")</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.VehicleModel.MakeId ,new SelectList(Model.VehcileMakeList, "MakeId","Make")))</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Enter Model </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.VehcileModel.Model)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.VehcileModel.Year )</td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

and in your action

```
ViewVMModel vm = new ViewVMModel();
vm.VehcileMakeList =  //get list of make 
vm.VehicleModel = new VehicleModel();
return view(vm);
```

Comment: View models should not contain data models!